Problem to show PhoneNumber to Datatable in Asp.Net Core MVC 6 project with Identity
I have a problem with data displaying to datatable.
I'm using the datatable in admin page of my Asp.Net Core MVC 6 project integrated the Identity for user management.
All the data is shown well, but the PhoneNumber column data isn't shown.
I checked it in the data fetching function, but I get the phonenumber correctly.



I hope the solution for this problem.

Hello! Please provide the resulting json from the /admin/getUserData route so we can see if the properties are being properly mapped.

I added the screenshot of JSON data. I found there are two PhoneNumber data there. How to show it correctly?

Hi @maxray, how is your model design? Did you custom IdentityUser model?

Yes, I derived the IdentityUser and included the PhoneNumber.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
...
[Phone]
[Display(Name = "phone.number")]
public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

I solved this problem by deleting the PhoneNumber attribute from the model derived from the IdentityUser.
That's because the IdentityUser has the PhoneNumber attribute by default.
So we don't have to include it to the customized model design.
Thanks to @Rena.
